# d3 no console errors and no SVG rendering

Tags: d3.js, svg

My CSV has columns named BookingID and Total Paid and I thought I was calling them correctly. Not sure where I'm going wrong here...

In index.html's header I have

I also had to add the above to the body of HTML because using just  gave me a d3.svg undefined error...

D3 seems to be loaded in the browser just fine, but my script doesn't execute. Nothing is rendered in the browser, and no error messages in the console.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.min.js">

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom")
.ticks(10);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left")
.ticks(10);


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
d3.csv("Sales Export Friendly 2-14-2017.csv", function(error, sales) {
    if (error) throw error;
    x.domain(sales.map(function(sale) { return sale.BookingID; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(sales, sales.map(function(sale) { return sale["Total Paid"]; }))]);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
.selectAll("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("dx", "-.8em")
  .attr("dy", "-.55em")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("$ USD");

svg.selectAll("bar")
  .sales(sales)
.enter().append("rect")
  .style("fill", "steelblue")
  .attr("x", function(sale) { return x(sale.BookingID); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(sale) { return y(sale["Total Paid"]); })
  .attr("height", function(sale) { return height - y(sale["Total Paid"]); });   

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have mixed script with `src` and content. Linked resource has precedence and the content is ignored in this case. It should be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> var // and the rest </script>
```

Comment: You're right that it's the problem but your explanation is inaccurate and/or confusing. All that is happening is that the inline script runs first and therefore fails because d3 isn't defined yet. It isn't "ignored".

Comment: No. Unless the d3.js (or any other really evaluated script in the document) looks for script elements with src attribute and artificially evaluates its content (it is possible and certain libraries uses this funny hack) the content between opening and closing tag is really ignored.

Comment: Oh right. I assumed because I've seen several libraries use variables declared in the content for configuration. Didn't realise these were `eval` hacks.